# TypeError Exception

Tags: python

###views.py###

```
def profile_interest_mempick(request,pk,code=None):  
"""allows user to subscribe to profile interests"""
me = Register.objects.get(user=request.user)
mem = Register.objects.get(pk=pk)
if code == 's':
     interests = mem.profile_interests.all()
 if not interests:
     content_string = "You currently have nothuing selected"
     return render_to_response("homepage/index.html", locals())
     else:
     content_string = "To unselect an interest please uncheck it's checkbox"
elif code == 'a':
interests = ProfileInterest.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
 form = profileInterestMemPickForm(request.POST, instance = mem)
 if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
 if Register.objects.get(pk=pk) == Register.objects.get(user = request.user):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/hallo/')
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/'.format(pk))
else:
 form = profileInterestMemPickForm(instance=me)
 form.fields["profile_interest"].queryset = interests
return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile_interest_mempick/')    
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in    
get_response
111.response = callback(request, *callback_args,  Exception **callback_kwargs)
```

Type: TypeError at /profile_interest_mempick/
   Exception Value: profile_interest_mempick() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Everything seems to be fine but it keeps on throwing this exception? any idea why?

Comment: This is a mess and impossible to read. Fix your indentations.

Answer (score 0):

Check url regular expression on urls.py.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Pattern should be as:

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^profile_interest_mempick/(?P\d{4})/$', 'news.views.profile_interest_mempick'),

Answer (score 0):

The traceback suggests that the problem isn't in the definition of profile_interest_mempick().  Instead, the problem lies with its caller using the wrong number of arguments.